# Unit Testing Spring Issues

Tags: java, spring, testing, mockito

I'm trying to learn how to do unit testing / mockito testing in spring with java 8 and running into some problems. I'm trying to test my method findUserById but it keeps running false. Optional type issues were an issue but may have resolved those. However, it still runs false. My other tests work, so its just this one test that is being stubborn. I would appreciate your help.

```
User Controller : 

 @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> findUserById(@PathVariable Integer id){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userServiceImp.findUserById(id));
    }
```

```
UserApplictionTester : 


  @Autowired
    private Service service;

   @MockBean
    private Repository repo;

@Test
    public void exampleTest() {

        User expectedUser = new User(3, "example@gmail.com", "password1", "exampleName", "USER");
        User testUser = new User();
        testUser.setId(3);
        when(repo.findById(any())).thenReturn(Optional.of(testUser));
        assertEquals(expectedUser, service.findUserById(testUser.getId()));
    }
```

Comment: I made a typo, Service should be UserService.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in your `Controller.findUserById` method you meant `ResponseEntity.of(...)` instead of `ResponseEntity.ok(...)` because `UserService.findUserById` returns `Optional<User>`. So assuming this is the case I can see at least two (potential) problems in your test:

1. You are asserting on two different types. The `expectedUser` is of type `User` whereas the actual user returned by `service.findUserById` is `Optional<User>`. They will never be equal even if the underlying value of `Optional<User>` is the same as `expectedUser`. I believe, the IDE should have highlighted it unless some inspections were disabled.
2. Not sure if `User.equals` and `User.hashCode` are properly defined. At first glance, even when you fix the first point your `testUser` and `expectedUser` might not be equal unless those methods are based only on the `User.id` ignoring the rest of the fields such as `email`, `password`, `name`, etc.